# Servlet filter for selective data capture

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, syslog

I have a third party Tomcat-based server application that I cannot change. The application receives POST requests from clients using the XML format. There is a business need to log some XML data fields from in a separate log file or into a database/syslog.
I am concerned about performance.

Is a servlet filter is a good solution for this case? 
Or it is better to use an intermediary proxy?

Could you recommend any existing filters/valves for this kind of needs?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the servlet filter you mentioned is implemented in the web application itself. So that may need to change the web.xml of the existing web application. Of course you can add another new webapp and redirect the request to the current webapp after the preprocessing.

However, Tomcat support Valves. I think it can perfectly support your requirements. A full Valve docs can be found in [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html). It DO has impacts on the overall performance on your webapp in some extent. It highly depends on how you implement your valve. You have to evaluate the performance overhead after your implementation.  The evaluation code can be also written in the valve class.

Here is another useful link:

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/11/finer-point-apache-tomcat-valves

After you implement your valves, you can register them in the configuration file under your tomcat directory.